# Script to delete records from SQL Server database on Azure using webjobs

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-webjobs

I want to run the following command daily on my Microsoft SQL Server database on free Azure portal account, to delete records older than 7 days from now.

```
USE [myMSSqlDatabaseName]
GO

DELETE FROM [dbo].[myTableName] 
WHERE [myDateFieldName] < GETDATE() - 7;
```

I have set up a scheduled webjob on my free Azure portal, the thing I'm missing is that they want me to upload a script that is supposed to be able to run this command. The script can be of many types, such as .cmd, .bat, .exe (using Windows cmd), .py etc.

I'm having trouble finding out how to convert my command to a running script. My preference would be Windows cmd script or Phyton scripts, as I have been working with Python and Windows.

Any clues?

Comment: *GETDATE() - 7* - not very clear - current date minus 7 .... 7 what?? Years?? Lightyears?? You should always be very **explicit** and thus use `DATEADD(DAY, -7, SYSDATETIME())`  instead. **NOW** it's crystal clear you mean 7 **days** before the current date&time ...

Comment: Logic Apps would be a better choice for this I think.  Call a stored procedure which did this task on a schedule.

Answer (score 0):

this website got me going, browsing to the header:

Connecting to an Azure SQL Database with PowerShell

There, finally there is a guy that really does this - [here](https://adamtheautomator.com/connect-to-azure-sql-database/)

p.s. my script to connect:
(and note, first I had to google how to allow powershell scripts to run on my pc. as by default one gets an error doing so, you need to google Set-execution policy).
... then I ran the command Install-Module Az  ,and note, did that while running powershell as administrator. Note, powershell needs restarting after changes so they take effect...
and then I ran the powershell command: Connect-AzAccount   (this connected to my account. perhaps not necessary, but gave me the confidence that I was connected).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I opened the bottle of champagne too early. - Thing is, I can run this script locally from my computer. But if I upload it to a webjob, the webjob does NOT do it's job. - In the log it claims to have ran successfully, but looking closer at the log, one can see it does not.

[04/20/2020 08:30:57 > fdc8de: SYS INFO] Status changed to Initializing
[04/20/2020 08:30:57 > fdc8de: SYS INFO] Run script 'ps.ps1' with script host - 'PowerShellScriptHost'
[04/20/2020 08:30:57 > fdc8de: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[04/20/2020 08:30:59 > fdc8de: ERR ] Import-Module : The specified module 'Az.Sql' was not loaded because no valid 
[04/20/2020 08:30:59 > fdc8de: ERR ] module file was found in any module directory.
[04/20/2020 08:30:59 > fdc8de: ERR ] At D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\x\f3qupf1g.kch\ps.ps1:1 char:1
[04/20/2020 08:30:59 > fdc8de: ERR ] + Import-Module Az.Sql -Force
[04/20/2020 08:30:59 > fdc8de: ERR ] + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[04/20/2020 08:30:59 > fdc8de: ERR ]     + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (Az.Sql:String) [Import-Mod 
[04/20/2020 08:30:59 > fdc8de: ERR ]    ule], FileNotFoundException
[04/20/2020 08:30:59 > fdc8de: ERR ]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm 
[04/20/2020 08:30:59 > fdc8de: ERR ]    ands.ImportModuleCommand
[04/20/2020 08:30:59 > fdc8de: ERR ]
[04/20/2020 08:31:03 > fdc8de: ERR ] Invoke-Sqlcmd : The term 'Invoke-Sqlcmd' is not recognized as the name of a 
[04/20/2020 08:31:03 > fdc8de: ERR ] cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
[04/20/2020 08:31:03 > fdc8de: ERR ] name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
[04/20/2020 08:31:03 > fdc8de: ERR ] At D:\local\Temp\jobs\triggered\x\f3qupf1g.kch\ps.ps1:18 char:3
[04/20/2020 08:31:03 > fdc8de: ERR ] +   Invoke-Sqlcmd  @Params
[04/20/2020 08:31:03 > fdc8de: ERR ] +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[04/20/2020 08:31:03 > fdc8de: ERR ]     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-Sqlcmd:String) [], Comma 
[04/20/2020 08:31:03 > fdc8de: ERR ]    ndNotFoundException
[04/20/2020 08:31:03 > fdc8de: ERR ]     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
[04/20/2020 08:31:03 > fdc8de: ERR ]
[04/20/2020 08:31:04 > fdc8de: SYS INFO] Status changed to Success